# How do I find objects of a model that fit a condition on an attribute, without using an iterator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a `Stock` model, which has a `ticker` attribute.

What I would like to do is find all the `Stock` objects where their `ticker.include?('at')`, without iterating over all objects using an enumerator.

I have tried `Stock.where("ticker.include?(?)", 'at')` but to no avail.

Comment: What type is `ticker` in the database and which database?

Comment: @muistooshort `ticker` is a `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not iterate, you need to do it in a declarative way: `SQL`. And to do it in `SQL`, you need a feature of the underlying `RDBMS`: `LIKE`, `ActiveRecord` is not enough (I think is possible in `Arel` though). 
Anyway, I take for granted two things here: your ticker field is a string, not an array, and your `RDBMS` is `MySQL` or `Postgresql`, and I go for

```
Stock.where("ticker LIKE ?", '%at%')
```

Comment: Or `Stock.where('ticker like ?', '%at%')`, minor point but a closer match to the question.

Comment: I was writing that way but then I thought is exactly the same with a fixed string. Is there any difference?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: There's no effective difference, just a bunch of habits reinforcing each other.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you want to use Arel only and no SQL. You can use the following:

```
Stock.where(Stock.arel_table[:ticker].matches('%at%'))
```

You could make a helper in your *ApplicationRecord* to ease the query.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.arel_attr(attr, method, *args)
    where(arel_table[attr].public_send(method, *args))
  end

end
```

Resulting in the query:

```
Stock.arel_attr(:ticker, :matches, '%at%')
```

For a full list of the methods you can call have a look at the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/Attributes/Attribute).